# video created by moviepy doesn't play on web

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm playing around with moviepy, with the intent of creating videos to imbed in webpages. However, I'm having trouble getting the videos that I create to actually play in chrome and firefox (it does play in safari :/ ).
Firefox claims the "file is corrupt".

I find it extremely likely I haven't installed something properly. I followed (among other things, since I'm not yet authorized to post enough links so as to fully describe my situation, #thanksStackOverflow ;P) http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/building-with-libvpx, but according to [link I would have shared if allowed :P] that stuff is all "automatically installed during MoviePy’s installation", so I'm not sure how I could have messed it up.

see example code (I've tried it with 'python', 'python3' and 'python3.5'):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

filepath = "../read_videos/MOVI0011.avi"
file = VideoFileClip(filepath)

clips = []
clips.append(file.subclip(10, 12))
clips.append(file.subclip(20, 22))
clips.append(file.subclip(30, 32))
clips.append(file.subclip(40, 42))

concatenated_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)

concatenated_clip.write_videofile("../write_videos/clip.mp4", fps=24, codec='mpeg4')
```

[firefox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWriG.png)

OSX El Capitan (10.11.3)

Comment: Any solution here?

Answer (score 0):

```
video = concatenate_videoclips(frames, method='compose')
video.write_videofile(gen_clip_name, fps=clip.fps, codec='mpeg4', audio_codec='aac')
```

Seems like you need `method='compose'` in `concatenate_videoclips`. You also need to explicitly set the audio and video codecs in `write_videofile`. I tried to use libx264 as the video codec but the resulting video wouldn't play in a browser without being set to mpeg4.